# Qual é a melhor forma de criar um model q tenha um campo que seja um enum de integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Qual é a melhor forma de criar um model q tenha um campo que seja um enum de integer ?
ex:rails g model status ( não sei como informar que é um enum nem o tipo do dado)

Answer (score 1):

Crie como inteiro, e depois configure o model:

rails g model pessoa status:integer

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um boolean para valores `true` ou `false`.

`status:boolean`